# Windows OS: Watchdog python defines deleting a folder as deleting a file

Tags: python, watchdog, python-watchdog

Decided to use the Watchdog library to keep track of folder changes in Windows. However, I discovered a very unfortunate problem. When defining the *on_deleted* function, I check the event via *event.is_directory*, but for some reason it fails the check and returns *False*. However, for the *on_created* function everything works fine. What is the problem? Maybe I am doing something wrong?
python *3.11.5*
watchdog *3.0.0*

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        if event.is_directory:
            print(f"directory created: {event.src_path}")
        else:
            print(f"file created: {event.src_path}")
            
    
    def on_deleted(self, event):
        if event.is_directory:
            print(f"directory deleted: {event.src_path}")
        else:
            print(f"file deleted: {event.src_path}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = MyHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    local_path = "C:\\Users\\dekus\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\sohri"
    observer.schedule(event_handler, local_path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    observer.join()
```

## Output

**directory created:** C:\Users\dekus\OneDrive\Desktop\sohri\Новая папка (5) --- for *on_created* it works fine
**file deleted**: C:\Users\dekus\OneDrive\Desktop\sohri\Новая папка (5) --- but for *on_deleted...*

Comment: Do you know that the operating system provides that information? If the object no longer exists and the notification API doesn't include the relevant data you can't check its type after it's gone; this may be something it's just not possible to implement (without the considerable expense of storing metadata about the directory tree up-front). I'd suggest looking at watchdog's source/comments, bugtracker, &c, but it wouldn't surprise me at all if this were simply a feature that wasn't available to implement on Windows in the first place.